# Are header files strictly necessary when the code is open source?

Tags: linker, compiler-theory

It was my understanding that header files were a developed practice, the header files created by copying all the externally-meaningful symbols from a source C file. Thus being able to give the linking information to a user and their compiler without giving them the source code.

Of course there is value in header files beyond the technical requirements of the compiler. This is outside the scope of my question. I am not asking for practical advice, that is to say, I'm not actively trying to link against a source c file, nor would I. I am trying to understand why it seems never to be done, under the impressions that there is no technical limitation (though there being a business limitation).

To phrase it a different way,

#### Could the complete source file be used for linking?

Technically speaking.

Comment: The linker can't link source code, only object files and libraries.

Comment: If you keep all your source code in a single C file, then headers are not strictly necessary.